# What dependency needed to write spring boot jms listener application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jms

Need to listen to rabbit mq queue .
What dependency needed ?
Its a pure listener project.
I just keep on listening queue and take some action.
Do we need spring.boot.starter.web ?
If not , how come application will keep on running infinitly ?
Which dependency to make it keep on listening event as if the main class running under loop ?

I added rabbit mq dependency and also web starter .But application just start the main class (annotated with @springbootapplication) and stops.

Answer (score 0):

based on the [spring guide - messaging](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/), you would need to add `spring-boot-starter-amqp`. In the same article says that another option could be go https://start.spring.io and select `Spring for RabbitMQ` as dependency. If you click on `Explore` button you can see that the `pom.xml` is similar to the one that you have in the [spring guide github repo for rabbit mq](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/blob/main/complete/pom.xml)